# Cannot reproduce results with Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm facing a mistery with keras. I'm following the example shown in the book "Practical machine learning with python".

I execute the following commands

```
    import keras
    from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
    cancer = load_breast_cancer()
    X_train = cancer.data[:340]
    y_train = cancer.target[:340]
    X_test = cancer.data[340:]
    y_test = cancer.target[340:]
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(15, input_dim=30, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=50)
```

This is the output (I am pasting only accuracy and loss) of the last line

```
    loss: 0.4130 - acc: 0.8500

    loss: 0.2211 - acc: 0.9147

    loss: 0.4366 - acc: 0.8441

    loss: 0.2292 - acc: 0.9118

    loss: 0.2547 - acc: 0.9029

    loss: 0.2399 - acc: 0.8941

    loss: 0.4907 - acc: 0.8618

    loss: 0.3180 - acc: 0.8853

    loss: 0.2452 - acc: 0.9029

    loss: 0.4381 - acc: 0.8588

    loss: 0.2242 - acc: 0.9029

    loss: 0.2700 - acc: 0.8941

    loss: 0.2022 - acc: 0.9118

    loss: 0.3545 - acc: 0.8559

    loss: 0.3242 - acc: 0.8882

    loss: 0.2504 - acc: 0.9147

    loss: 0.5074 - acc: 0.8676

    loss: 0.1980 - acc: 0.9353

    loss: 0.3794 - acc: 0.8882

    loss: 0.2567 - acc: 0.9000
```

Then I repeat the same steps for the same model with a different name

```
    model2 = Sequential()
    model2.add(Dense(15, input_dim=30, activation='relu'))
    model2.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
    model2.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
    model2.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model2.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=50)
```

This is the output of the last line (again, I will show only acc. and loss)

```
     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382

     loss: 7.3616 - acc: 0.5382
```

Why I don't get the same result (a much greater accuracy and a much lesser loss)?

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this consistently happen? Have you tried running multiple times because random weights can cause this?

Comment: Yes I tried unsuccessfully.. Can you try on your pc and let me know if you get the same results?

Comment: searching on internet I found this page that explain about that subject https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by specifying a kernel_initializer

```
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
```

Thank everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

That is totally normal.

Model weights are initialized randomly. Sometime a model starts with better luck than another.

Since you're using "relu" and just a few neurons (15), there is also the possibility of all your relu outputs being zero, and this the backpropagation cannot happen. This results in a frozen model, like in your second example.

For using "relu" activations, a proper weight initialization and a proper learning rate must be selected to avoid this effect. (I'm not an expert in this part, though).

If you want to see reproductible results, you need to set a constant random seed before you run the code. (And probably you will need to restart your python kernel whenever you want to create a new model)

```
import random
random.seed(chooseAnInteger)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try and I will let you know (even though I think I tried your solution); the strange thing is that in the part of the book I am reading, the author is trying to explain how adding a second hidden layer (calling two times the method model2.add(Dense(15, activation='relu')) will enhance the learning rate (and so, reduce loss and improve accuracy). He also shows that if I don't add the second hidden layer I will obtain the exact result I am obtaining in the second case (model2.fit(...))

Comment: Hi Daniel, it doesn't work. Now i have both a constant loss (high) and a constant accuracy (low) as the second example:
loss: 8.6753 - acc: 0.4618

Comment: Read the part about "relu".

Comment: Use another activation, such as "softplus" or "tanh"

Comment: Same problem if I change the activation. The strange thing is that I am just trying to reproduce an example from a book (copying and pasting code).